# Airflow tasks overlapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I only want one DAG to be able to run before the next one is triggered.

I often have multiple overlapping dag runs.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean 1 Dag running at a time out of all your dags, or do you only want Dag X to have 1 dag run at a time?

Comment: Dag X to have 1 dag run at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the documentation, max_active_runs seems to be what I'm looking for:

```
class DAG(BaseDag, LoggingMixin):
    ...
    param concurrency: the number of task instances allowed to run
    concurrently
    :type concurrency: int
    :param max_active_runs: maximum number of active DAG runs, beyond this
    number of DAG runs in a running state, the scheduler won't create
    new active DAG runs
```

therefore, either

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2017,1,1),
    max_active_runs=1,
    )
```

or

```
dag.max_active_runs = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be configured in Airflow settings:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-active-runs-per-dag

1. In airflow.cfg, set *max_active_runs_per_dag = 1*
2. As environment variable, set *AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_RUNS_PER_DAG = 1*

Comment: You might want to give some more details, like a example config or a screenshot showing how to configure

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with those details